# Adding html to a crispy form in django

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I want to customize one of my fields from my form. I would like to add a span tag to one of the input fields and apply a div and some classes.

How do I apply these changes to a form rendered with crispy forms?

Comment: What you’ve tried so far?

Comment: Im trying to add some html to replace one of the form fields so I can apply a datepicker. I've tried crispy Layouts and using widgets

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Please post your current code. Btw have you followed the docs at https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html